# My pc boots directly to Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, partitioning, windows-7

I had installed windows 7 and after that i tried to install ubuntu 14.04 with usb as dual boot. I did the disk partitioning by clicking something else at the installation prompt window. I also left space for swap area. I think that I have made mistake in the mount point since i chose '/'. Now when I restart the pc it directly boots from ubuntu(it doesnt show the grup menu) and at the hard drives it only shows the 30 GB I had saved for ubuntu (it doesn't show my windows hard drives). Are my windows files saved and is it possible to return this action?

Comment: What's the output of `sudo lsblk -f` and `sudo os-prober`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to boot into Windows after installing Ubuntu, how to fix?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/217904/unable-to-boot-into-windows-after-installing-ubuntu-how-to-fix)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Using Windows installation DVD for Boot repair may do the trick. For details, please see http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/32523/how-to-manually-repair-windows-7-boot-loader-problems/

Hope it will help. Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend [edit]ing this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on Ask Ubuntu.)

Comment: Thank you. It worked and I will install Ubuntu from the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Once you login to Ubuntu Linux you should open the terminal(Ctrl+Alt+T) and then issue the following commands

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

to install [boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) and fix this issue.